# PayPal ExpressCheckout implementation - import error, missing jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, paypal

Trying to implement PayPal express checkout feature in my Java Project.

IDE used is Eclipse.

From the documentation in PayPal I understand I need to call two PayPal REST APIs

1. SetExpressCheckout
2. DoExpressCheckoutPayment

I downloaded the merchant SDK from http://paypal.github.io/sdk/#merchant and added paypal-core-1.4.4.jar and merchantsdk-2.5.106.jar to Eclipse project build path.

I want to write REST setExpressCheckout function in my class which will call PayPal::setExpressCheckout.

I am trying to import com.paypal.soap.api.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType and I get an error.

The snippet am trying to write is

```
SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType setExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();

setExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.setVersion("63.0");
```

Is there a jar file I am missing?

-RK

Comment: check class com.paypal.soap.api.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType contain in the jar

Comment: What is the error you get?  Please copy and paste it into the question.

Comment: I am not sure if the class structure changed in PayPal. I found SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType class in urn.ebay.apis.eBLBaseComponents.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsTypepackage and not in com.paypal.soap.api.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType

Answer (score 0):

Class 'SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType' is found in urn.ebay.apis.eBLBaseComponents.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType

But According to http://jerrythedog.com/docs/com/paypal/soap/api/SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType.html, this class must be in com.paypal.soap.api.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType

wondering if paypal package structure changed? Do they now have ebay package?

-RK